# Icons in MultiCollider Dropdown are wrong on Gaming's Blog site

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, blog-overflow

When you click the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ on a `blog.` subdomain, the Stack Exchange icon is used instead of the icons for the community the blog is for.

Screenshot demonstrating the issue:

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be unique to Arqade (compare others listed on http://stackexchange.com/blogs). I wonder if it's got anything to do with the way it's hosted...Doesn't seem to be on Blog Overflow like the rest of 'em.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We figure out where to look for icons based on the site's URL, and since Arqade was a rebranding effort and not the original name for Gaming Stack Exchange, the same pattern-matching we do for other blogs just doesn't work.

I updated the blog theme to pull the icons from the correct folder, so this is fixed now.